# How to add module in Intellij 14 to existing project

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14

Recently moved to Intellij from eclipse it seems to be tough to have this setup in intellij 14. [image]

Note: I cannot use maven

Steps I have followed created a "test project" and "test project 2"
-> opened test project project structure in cmd+; (shortcut in mac)
-> in project settings modules clicked on "+" and selected "import module" option
-> selected project 2

-> I got this error message stating that

> cannot  save settings, must not contain source root /test/src. The root belongs to module test`

This link is more confusing , could not understand much
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html

Can any one explain how to solve this?

Comment: is no one is using intellij :?

Comment: What do you see in IDEA under Project Structure (use CMD + ; to open it, then Project Settings - Modules)?

Comment: @DenisMakarskiy some how I cannot open intellij as it stucks all the all time while indexing , but can you tell me what i should look into that tab

Comment: You will see there all source and test source folders for all modules, check if they are correct.

Comment: i have never changed those parts, all I have done is imported those projects from eclipse, do i need to manually configure them as source ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse's concepts of "workspace" and "project" are matched by IntelliJ IDEA's "project" and "module" respectively. So to achieve similar setup as in your screenshot, create an ampty project, and import the modules "core", "model". .. to it.

Then open the "File > Project Structure" and check and adjust each module's "sources" and "test sources' folder. Make sure no source or test source overlap (this is the reason you got the "cannot save settings" error).

See for example the screenshot below. The project is called "test" and is in "C:\Projects\test". The module "springapp" is in "C:\Projects\test\springapp", its sources are marked "C:\Projects\test\springapp\src", its test sources are "C:\Projects\test\springapp\test". The same for the other modules.

Especially note that no one of the modules marks the root folder "C:\Projects\test\" as a "sources" or "test sources" (As I wrote above this is the reason for the error you got).

[image]

Comment: I have a weird scenario, for me the new module doesn't show Mark as: Source, Tests, Resources, Test Resources. It only shows "Excluded".

Comment: Could you help me after doing this, how can I use some function from `utility` module in another module? I'm stuck :/

Answer (score 1):

In Project Settings you can "Add Content Root".

Answer (score 0):

File -> Project Structure -> Modules (On left panel) -> + (addition sign) -> import module -> choose module with file chooser -> import recursively -> apply and ok. That should do it